# How can I change the shape of a gridview to circular?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview

How can I change the square shape of a GridView to circular or is it possible to display a gridview on a circular object or say an image?

I have tried to :-

```
1-add cssclass to the gridview where css class had a line of code for a background image
2-applied headerclass css to the gridview and gave the image source there.
3-applied a backimage property to the Grid.
(the image in all the 3 cases was a circle)
```

css is

```
    .circle{ background:url(circle.png); opacity:0.5;height:176px;width:176px;}
```

and i m trying to insert the `GridView` in my aspx page in visual studio 10

But nothing seems to work the way i want . The GridView Cells were misaligned in first 2 cases.

Please suggest me  a right way if possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's your CSS and Markup?

Comment: css is  ...`.circle{ background:url(circle.png); opacity:0.5;height:176px;width:176px;} `
and i m trying to insert in my aspx page in visual studio 10

Comment: edit your post, please.

Comment: Can you post a Fiddle? You can copy HTML markup rendered by the GridView and add your CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use an image, just use CSS to form a circle, for example

```
.circle {
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    background: LightPink;
    -moz-border-radius: 160px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 160px;
    border-radius: 160x;
}
```

Also, don't change shape of the grid itself - it may cause misalignments. Place the grid inside of a DIV with above class applied.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pnFGt/

Comment: @YuriyThank you so much, it worked , just have to align the columns now.
PS-The gridview is in a div already which has a class defined with javascript code which has a jquery linked to it.